# Using repaint() in different class instances in one panel

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, repaint

I have a draw class that extends JPanel and has a void method called drawing with `repaint()` in it.

```
public class draw extends JPanel {

    public draw(int position_x, int position_y, int width, int height) {
        positionx = position_x;
        positiony = position_y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void drawing() {

        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(positionx, positiony, width, height);
    }
}
```

So, my intention is create a lot of this rectangles in a JPanel so they create a graphic bar.

```
public class coin_launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Coin Launcher");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        draw object = new draw(2,2,100,2);
        frame.add(object);
        object.drawing();

        draw object2 = new draw(2,6,200,2);
        frame.add(object2);
        object2.drawing();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call `drawing()` in both of the objects only one gets drawn. 
If use the debugger its only the first one, if I dont, its only the second one. I need to make 100 bars but it literally repaints the `JPanel` every time, how can I add different draw class in one `JPanel` without erasing the others?

Comment: To make your code easy to read, please indent it and follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/).

Answer (score 1):

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, this means that only the last component added (to the default centre position) will be managed by the layout.

See [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border) for more details.

An immediate solution might be to use a different layout manager, but I would argue that's the wrong solution.

Instead, you should have ONE component, which is capable of paint multiple bars, based on the data available from a "model"

This decouples the source of the data from the presentation of the data, allowing to produce multiple different implementations of these, which shouldn't break the other.

In this case, the "view" shouldn't care how the data is obtained or marinated, only that it conforms to a specified contract, like wise the data doesn't care how its presented.

See [Model-View-Controller](https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a very basic and simplified example of

> "you should have ONE component, which is capable of paint multiple
>   bars, based on the data available from a "model"

quoted from [MadProgrammer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53875984/3992939).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CoinLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Coin Launcher");
        frame.setSize(920, 480);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //data to be painted. for better implementation use a model class that 
        //encapsulates the data     
        Rectangle[] bars = {         
            new Rectangle(2,2,100,2),
            new Rectangle(2,6,200,2),
        };

        Draw object = new Draw(Arrays.asList(bars));
        frame.add(object);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Draw extends JPanel {

    private final List<Rectangle> bars;

     Draw(List<Rectangle> bars) {
         this.bars = bars;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        for(Rectangle bar : bars){
            g.fillRect(bar.x, bar.y, bar.width, bar.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Implementing a model to encapsulate data need for the view, can be as simple as :

```
public class CoinLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Coin Launcher");
        frame.setSize(920, 480);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Model model = new Model();
        model.addBar( new Rectangle(2,2,100,2) );
        model.addBar( new Rectangle(2,6,200,2) );

        Draw object = new Draw(model);
        frame.add(object);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Draw extends JPanel {

    private final List<Rectangle> bars;

     Draw(Model model) {
         bars = model.getBars();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        for(Rectangle bar : bars){
            g.fillRect(bar.x, bar.y, bar.width, bar.height);
        }
    }
}

class Model {

    private final List<Rectangle> bars;

    Model(){
        bars = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void addBar(Rectangle rectangle){
        bars.add(rectangle);
    }

    List<Rectangle> getBars() { return bars; }
}
```